# Rails4 Help write a clean scope through multiple levels of related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**Background**

I have 4 models (user, foo, bar, baz) and they are all associated as follows:

- GIVEN the `user` model that `has_many :foos`
- AND that the `foo` model `has_many :bars`
- AND that the `bar` model `has_many :bazs`

**What I want to do**

I have a sidebar on several pages that I would like to populate the `user's` `baz` for the current date. I have the dirty way to do it: iterate through all of the related models to until I get to `baz`.

I was thinking of creating a scope for it but I am not entirely sure how to do that when the data I want is from some other model, which is 3 associations away.

*As a side note: my intention is to get the `user's` `baz` for the current date but it is not guaranteed that there will be a `baz` for any given day

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just define this as a scope in your User model?

```
scope :baz_for_date, -> (date) {
  foos.bars.bazs.
  where("bazs.created_at >= ? AND bazs.created_at < ?", date, date+1.day)
}
```

**Edit**

Just realized you only want it for the current day, in that case use the following:

```
scope :baz_for_today, -> {
  foos.bars.bazs.where("bazs.created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_day)
}
```